# How can you reference a object with a class variable?

Tags: php, class

I couldn't find a answer to my question and I am thinking there is something easy I am missing..

I am trying to reference a a value within a object with a variable in a class. In this case I want the line on the bottom:

```
echo $b->ref->$a->type
```

to output 'testing' like the following two will:

```
echo $b->ref->test; // outputs 'testing'
$c = $a->type;
echo $b->ref->$c; // outputs 'testing'
```

Full code:

```
    <?php

class A {

    public $type;

    public function set_type($type) {
        $this->type = $type;
    }
}

class B {
    public $ref;

    public function set_reference($ref) {
        $this->ref = $ref;
    }

}

$a = new A();
$b = new B();
$b->set_reference( (object) array('test' => 'testing', 'test2' => 'testing2') );

$a->set_type('test');

echo $b->ref->test; // outputs 'testing'
echo '<br />';
echo $a->type; // outputs 'test'
echo '<br />';

$c = $a->type;

echo $b->ref->$c; // outputs 'testing'
echo '<br />';

echo $b->ref->$a->type; // error
```

What am I missing to be able to do this? Or, is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as always.

```
echo $b->ref->{$a->type};
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew this was something simple I did not know about. I will accept the answer shortly when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this:

```
echo $b->ref->{$c};
```